# CompletableFuture is Not waiting for child threads

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I am trying to wait for `processor.processFiles()` to complete, the method returns void and it is an @Async method. The busy wait logic does not cause the process to wait for method to complete.
Can anybody please point out what am i missing?

```
try{

    filesList.forEach(files -> {
        List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures  = new ArrayList<>();

        files.forEach(file-> {
            CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> 
                processor.processFiles());
            completableFutures.add(completableFuture);
        });
        while(true) {

            Thread.sleep(5000);
            boolean isComplete = completableFutures.stream().allMatch(result -> result.isDone() == true);

            if(isComplete){
                break;
            }
            LOGGER.info("processing the file...");
        }
    });
} 
catch(Exception e){

}
finally{
    closeConnections();
}
```

Comment: You can get rid off that loop by using `CompletableFuture.allOf(completableFutures).get()`. This will create a new `CompletableFuture` that will only end when all given `CompletableFutures` end; the `get()` will return `null` because that's the only valid value for its generic type - `Void`. Just ignore it.

Comment: This is really strange. Why do you iterate over the files but you dont' do anything with the file you're getting? You should not use a forEach if you're going to stuff the results into another collection, you should stream/collect. You could probably use a forEach and a parallel stream though, and never use a completable future at all.

Comment: Hi Matt, I am not iterating over files but only the metadata of files, filename, creation date, etc.

Comment: @sharad You're iterating over something called "file" but you never use it in your processor.processFiles().

Comment: If `processor.processFiles()` is `@Async`, then it returns instantly and runs something in background, but your code is never checking for that background task.

Comment: So it's async within async? Change `processFiles` to return a future, wait for that future to complete. Don't use a future to start dispatch another future

Comment: Are you using Spring? It seems like your `CompletableFuture.runAsync` is a bit of a red herring. You probably shouldn't be using that at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've overcomplicated things.

```
fileList.flatMap(List::stream).parallel().forEach(file -> processor.processFiles());
```

The forEach will run in parallel, and return when all of the files have been processed.

At the very least, don't use side effects to populate a `List`.

```
List<CompletableFuture<Void>> completableFutures  = files.stream().map(
    file ->  CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> processor.processFiles());
).collect( Collectors.toList());
```

I agree with the comment.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf( completableFutures );
```

Then you can use `get` which will wait until the tasks are completed.

Another way to do this, that would skip the List + CompletableFuture.allOf and just return a single completable future.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> all = files.stream().map(
        file ->  CompletableFuture.runAsync(
            () -> processor.processFiles()
        )
    ).collect( 
        Collectors.reducing( 
           CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null), CompletableFuture::allOf
        )
    );
```

That will map `file` to a CompletableFuture then merge all of the resulting completable futures into a single completable future. You can call .get on it and it will return when everything is finished.